# SqlServer to Oracle PLSQL conversion

Tags: sql-server, oracle, plsql, sql-server-2008-r2, oracle-sqldeveloper

How this sqlserver code should look like in Oracle?

```
set @Date= (select Convert(nvarchar(30), (select YEAR(Getdate()))) + 
            Convert(nvarchar(10), (SELECT RIGHT('00' + @month, 2))) + 
            Convert(nvarchar(10), (SELECT RIGHT('00' + @day, 2))));
```

Comment: Unrelated to solution, but are you storing a date as text?

Comment: provide us what you have and what you expect: input and output

Answer (score 1):

```
some_var := to_char(sysdate,'yyyy-mm-dd');
```

More details on the `to_char()` function are in the manual:
 http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions200.htm#SQLRF06129